# Is there a way to generate a zfproject.xml file from an existing Zend project/application?

Tags: zend-framework

I'm on Debian Lenny if that matters, in terms of me possibly needing something like Zend Studio - I'm wondering if `Zend_Tool` can do this somehow.

Comment: What is a zfproject.xml file?

Comment: It is an xml file that contains the structure of your zend app when you use the cli to create a new site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guess there isn't an easy practical way ( yet at least )

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure you know this information already but I thought I'd mention it here for posterity.

It looks as if Ralph Schindler has been working on features within Zend Tool but I don't believe they're in place yet. The process, as I understand it, would be to create a fresh ZF project, move in your existing structure, and then use Zend Tool to re-sync the .zfproject.xml file. I've heard you can re-call "zf create" commands to have them insert nodes into the .zfproject.xml file but I've not seen it done. And, besides, you specified "practical".